# Error defining widget Toolbar in Android Studio

Tags: android, toolbar

I'm trying to code a navigation drawer using the new way to do it. My problem at the moment comes when trying to define my own app toolbar.

Here is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_top_padding"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomToolBarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is the app_bar.xml

In the preview of android studio, when trying to render it I'm getting the following error:

*Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
-Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme (4 similar errors not shown)

-"?attr/actionBarSize" in attribute "minHeight" is not a valid format. (Edit) (2 similar errors not shown)*

How could I solve it??

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error and solved it by changing the `parent` attribute in my `style.xml` file. The solution is to use parent theme same as your Application theme, like below:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@color/title_color</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

And my Toolbar Widget:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/title_bar"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    style="@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I suggest you to put your color customizations in `styles.xml` instead of toolbar widget.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question. You must use an action bar theme as

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"> </style>
```

and the correct sintax for the attr is:

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

Answer (score 0):

After stuggling for a while, these code work for me:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyCustomToolbarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ToolbarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

May be it's just missing `toolbarStyle` field and need to be filled in.